# Static function in template class

Tags: c++, function, templates, static

I'm trying to create a sort of factory class in a template.  I wanted to do something like a pure virtual function, but it needs to be static as I'm using the function to create types.

What I want to happen is when I declare a class, the template calls the static function.  The static function is actually declared in the templatised class.

I've got as far as:

```
class Base
{

};

template<typename T>
class Type : public Base
{
public:
    static void Create()
    {
        mBase = CreateBase();
    }

private:
    static Base* CreateBase();

    static Base* mBase;
};

class MyType : public Type<MyType>
{
private:        
    static Base* CreateBase()
    {
        return new MyType;
    }
};

template<typename T>
Base* Type<T>::mBase = NULL;

void test()
{
    MyType::Create();
}
```

I get a link time error:

```
undefined reference to `Type<MyType>::CreateBase()
```

Comment: See also [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

The problem was I wasn't calling the derived class' function.

Here is the fix:

```
static void Create()
{
    mBase = T::CreateBase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CreateBase` function is defined in the base type, so just call it:

```
template<typename T>
class Type : public Base
{
public:
    static void Create()
    {
        mBase = Base::CreateBase();
    }
//...
```

There is no need to declare another `CreateBase` in the template.

Comment: The problem isn't that I can't call it, it's that this code doesn't link.

Comment: @Neil: In `Create` you are calling `Type<>::CreateBase` that is not defined, and thus the linker fails. The proposed solution is **not** calling `Type<>::CreateBase` (don't even declare it!) and directly call `Base::CreateBase`, which is defined in `MyType` and will link appropriately.